# JQuery SlideToggle Width Expanding

Tags: jquery, width, slidetoggle

Hey guys,

I have a glitch in my JQuery. When I hover over each tab area and move horizontally .panel seems to lose its width attribute and either expand or shrink when it slides toggles up. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/5nEXB/

JQuery

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $("li.nav").hover(function()
    {
        var x = $(this).offset().left;
        var y = $(this).offset().top;
        //var w = $(this).width();
        var totalWidth = $(this).width();
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt($(this).css("padding-right"), 10); //Total Padding Width
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"), 10) + parseInt($(this).css("margin-right"), 10); //Total Margin Width
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt($(this).css("borderRightWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width
        var h = $(this).height();

        //$("#navigation").find(".panel").stop().slideToggle("fast");
        $("#navigation").find(".panel").animate({
            top: y,
            left : x
        }, 0 ).css({'width' : totalWidth,
            '40px' : h,
            'position' : 'absolute'}).slideDown(200).css('display','block');

    }, function() {
        $("#navigation").find(".panel").stop().slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
body, html {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background:url(../../Portfolio/images/wood2.png);
}

a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
font-family:open-sans, HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold, Helvetica Neue, serif;
-webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.4s ease;
transition:all 0.4s ease;
}

a:visited {
color:#000;
}

a:hover {
color:#FFF;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.4s ease;
transition:all 0.4s ease;
}

#navigation {
width:auto;
height:40px;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .45);
min-width:700px;
}

ul#nav {
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;
overflow:auto;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

li.nav {
display:inline-block;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
position:relative;
height:30px;
float:left;
border-bottom:none;
}

ul li.nav a {
display:block;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
}

* html ul li a {
width: 1%;
}

.panel {
position:absolute;
background:#363;
background-size:100%;
height:40px;
display:none;
width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">GIFT REGISTRY</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior. What browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the usage overlap in .panel. You're using the same element in chronologically overlapping transition events.

When you leave a tab, .panel is set to the width of the tab it's used for next.

You'll either need to instantly hide the panel on leaving a tab, or use individual panels for each tab.

UPDATE: Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/5nEXB/1/

```
.panel {z-index: -1;}

<div id="navigation">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="nav">
            <div class="panel"></div><a href="#">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <div class="panel"></div><a href="#">OUR STORY</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <div class="panel"></div><a href="#">GALLERY</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <div class="panel"></div><a href="#">GIFT REGISTRY</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(function () {
    $("li.nav").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".panel").slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".panel").slideUp();
    });
});
```

If you didn't want to put all those .panel divs in your HTML you could prepend them using jQuery on hover.

If, for some reason, you wanted to stick with your original approach, you could do the instant hide: http://jsfiddle.net/5nEXB/2/

Comment: Do you have an example? My apologies I am still learning JQuery.

Comment: Thought you might appreciate that. :-)